# redirect url with query string to another url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect the following URL

```
http://www.mydomain.com/catalogsearch/result/index/?brand=1076&mode=grid&product_category=5533&q=pro+restore
```

To this URL:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/nsearch/?q=pro+restore
```

This is the code I've used for other urls in htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/catalogsearch/result/index/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^brand=1076&mode=grid&product_category=5533&q=pro+restore$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/nsearch/?q=pro+restore [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't work.  Any ideas on what I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^brand=1076&mode=grid&product_category=5533&(q=pro\+restore)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^catalogsearch/result/index/?$ /nsearch/?%1 [R=301,L]
```